# what is the difference between creating a profile and a policy to restrict a user in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-security

Taking a course on Oracle database security, I have learned profiles are being created to restrict access of some users to some resources.On the other hand, we have functions and policies, which can restrict users too, but I cannot clear the difference between these two. Why we use profiles while we can create policies for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Profile restricts how much system resource a user is allowed: how many concurrent sessions they can have, how much CPU they can use, etc. We can also use Profiles for password management: how many failed logins they're allowed, how long a password lasts, etc.

So a Profile defines the broad bounds of system usage. It governs hardware and database access.

By "policy" I assume you mean Fine-Grained Access Control. These policies set limits to what a user can see of an individual table: what rows they can see and what columns. So we could.use FGAC policy to allow a manager to see all the details for their direct reports but only certain information for all other employees.

So a Policy applies further restrictions to a table which a user *already has access to*. Which highlights the missing **P** from your question.

A Privilege grants a user permission to do a specific thing. By default a user cannot do anything in a database. They can't even connect to it without the CREATE SESSION privilege. There are two levels of Privilege. A System Privilege allows a user to do general activities like create a table, execute any procedure, query the data dictionary, etc. A Table Privilege allows a user to do something with a specific object owned by a different user, such as select from `my.employee_table`, execute `her.string_function`, etc.

So you can see how Privileges and FGAC Policies interact. I might grant you select and update on `my.employee_table` but enforce a policy that only allows you to update records for department 40.

To summarise. There are four levels of user restrictions.
In descending order of breadth:

1. Profile
2. System Privilege
3. Table (i.e. Object) Privilege
4. FGAC Policy

---

Note: 12c introduced some called an Audit Policy. Clearly that is relevant to the general topic of Oracle database security but I don't think it's pertinent here.